# Formatting text in R Shiny

Tags: shiny

I am developing an application in R Shiny. One of my modules in the application, displays dynamic text depending on user inputs. I would like to display the text as bullet points and additionally would like the text in "strong" or "heading" format. I can do this individually but somehow I am  not able to figure out how to combine the 2. So assuming that my function returns a character vector a, with 2 components that I need to display, I can do the following:

```
HTML("<ul><li>",a[1],"</li><li>",a[2]) #To generate bullet points
HTML(paste(h4(a[1],a[2],sep='')))  #To concatenate and change format to heading
```

Now my question is - How can I do both (display as bullets with heading format)? I tried different combinations but it's not working.
Secondly, how do I change the colour of my text?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a bullet list with heading format, you can just add an `<h4>` tag to the `paste`. Also, make sure you close all the tags you open, for ex:

```
  HTML("<ul'><li><h4>",a[1],"</h4></li><li><h4>",a[2],"</h4></li></ul>")
```

You can use inline CSS to change the color, for ex:

```
HTML("<ul style='color:red'><li><h4>",a[1],"</h4></li><li><h4>",a[2],"</h4></li></ul>")
```

More info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_text.asp).

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot. Exactly what I wanted.